# Return type 'never' if an optional parameter is given to be a specific value

Tags: typescript, function, overloading, typing

I have a function that takes an optional `boolean` argument that defaults to `false`. When the argument is `false`, the function returns a `string`. When the argument is `true`, the function should return type `never`.

Here's what I tried:

```
function example(arg: true): never;
function example(arg = false): string {
  //...
}
```

This feels like it should work: `arg` is inferred to have a `boolean` type, and when it is not passed or passed as `false`, `example` returns `string`. When it is passed as `true`, the overload kicks in and `example` returns `never`.

However, this doesn't work at all. TypeScript gives `arg` the type `true` and makes it required and makes `example` *always* return `never`.

I also tried this craziness, and got closer:

```
function example(arg: false): string;
function example(arg: true): never;
function example(arg: boolean): string | never;
function example(arg = false): string | never {
  //...
}
```

However the compiler still doesn't consider `arg` to be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function example(arg: true): never;
function example(arg?: false): string;
function example(arg: boolean): string;
function example(arg: boolean = false): never | string {
    if (!arg) {
        return 'foo';
    }

    throw new Error();
}

const foo = example(true); // typeof foo is never
const bar = example(false); // typeof bar is string
const baz = example(); // typeof baz is string
```

[Link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCnQCcBzALkSmJGQEpKxkA3ZYgbgChRJYEUMOfETIB+SsHS4AzvUrTqMMKS49o8JGix5CJCogBGcOPnRgGiBcSUru4dfy1DdZSkZPIziALyJJMuUQmVmJEAB9LRWVEAG9ORATEGGBEAgBCPTpY+MTc4mQoEGIkAHJgYxKuXIBfThyEqAALYjgAdyDkdoBRYhbiAjouWs4IBAU-Yx8BbWFqWkHEAHpFqgBPbGQ4FPK4JOkOkJGxqEMSKacdAn9ZBeW1ja3T0Jh9qxsjsHGDdAAvc8FLrcVlB1psUt8-i9ItZlEA)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work using your code but adding an additional overload `example(arg: boolean): never | string` for cases when the passed variable is of type `boolean` and not `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Ian, ah, I missed that part! Updated the answer.